# Nemo file manager - only "Eject" no "Safely remove device" for some USB flash sticks

Tags: usb-drive, nemo

I don't see the option when using a Sony USB 3.0 flash. With USB 2.0 Kingstons it is there.

Can somebody confirm this as normal behaviour for USB 3.0 devices in Nemo file manager(v. 3.2.2)?

Comment: Seems to be return of well known [bug 1067876](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1067876). Caja sometimes do the same.

Comment: Pretty grim as eject seems to only umount the drive without checking if syncing is in progress so data corruption is a distinct possibility. Do you know of a way to check for any pending syncing operation? I found the progress dialog useless in this respect.

Comment: If I remember correctly sync syscall is executed before eject. If unsure you can use `gnome-disks` to shutdown drive.